# MEF Error message

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mef

Can anybody explain this error message:

> The composition remains unchanged. The
>   changes were rejected because of the
>   following error(s): The composition
>   produced a single composition error.
>   The root cause is provided below.
>   Review the CompositionException.Errors
>   property for more detailed
>   information.
>
> 1) No valid exports were found that
>   match the constraint
>   '((exportDefinition.ContractName ==
>   "Silverbits.ApplicationServices.ApplicationServicesManager")
>   AndAlso
>   (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity")
>   AndAlso
>   "Silverbits.ApplicationServices.ApplicationServicesManager".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))',
>   invalid exports may have been
>   rejected.
>
> Resulting in: Cannot set import
>   'Silverbits.Applications.SilverbitsApplication.ApplicationServices
>   (ContractName="Silverbits.ApplicationServices.ApplicationServicesManager")'
>   on part 'Framework.App'. Element:
>   Silverbits.Applications.SilverbitsApplication.ApplicationServices
>   (ContractName="Silverbits.ApplicationServices.ApplicationServicesManager")
>   -->  Framwork.App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `ApplicationServicesManager` class may be available and marked with an `[Export]` attribute, this part may still have been rejected because it has itself imports which cannot be satisfied.

Take a look at the section [Diagnosing Composition problems](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debugging%20and%20Diagnostics&referringTitle=Guide) in the MEF documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for something like this:

```
[Export]
public class ApplicationServicesManager
{
}
```

or like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [Export]
    public ApplicationServicesManager AppServices { get; private set; }
}
```

But it can't find one in the scope of your provided exports.  If you're Exporting it from a property or field, make sure the object exporting it has been composed with the container.  If it's a class export and the class is present in another assembly, make sure the assembly is in the container's catalog.

Comment: I'm using Silverlight 4.0 so I'm not dealing with catalog's, rather I am using the suggested method:

CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);

Comment: BTW That still does not solve my problem, as I have exported the ApplicationServicesManager. It's a class in another assembly, but is it included in the xap file, so it should resolve.

Comment: SatisfyImports will use an implicitly created global container with a standard catalog, but it should hopefully be set up to use every assembly in the XAP to look for exports; I haven't used MEF with Silverlight, so I'm not entirely sure.  In any case, the error is definitely a failure to resolve the Export.  I've seen this problem when my class exporting a service as a property wasn't properly composed in the container I was using.